# storing 3 arraylist into one list in asp.net/c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, arraylist

I have three `ArrayLists` with `string` elements and I want to store them into one `List`/`ArrayList`/`String Array`/`Dictionary`.

I mean I want to add them. I don't know which one How can I do it? What should I use?

It is in asp.net/c#.

Please help me!

Thank you in anticipation!

Comment: There are some things missing in the question. What language are you using (at least Java and .net have something called "ArrayList")? What is stored in the lists? Strings or other kinds of objects? How would you like to combine the lists? Concatenate or create a list of lists, or...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a new ArrayList and add each existing ArrayList to it using AddRange():

```
System.Collections.ArrayList One = { "Hello", "World" };
System.Collections.ArrayList Two = { "Second", "Array" };

System.Collections.ArrayList NewList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
NewList.AddRange(One);
NewList.AddRange(Two);
```

You will have all Items in the NewList

```
{"Hello", "World", "Second", "Array"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java?

java.util.HashMap:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 0):

use the [addAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) function